# Coordinate Transformation Difference between QGIS and Proj

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, proj, pyproj

I transformed coordinates on PyQgis and Proj command line and there is 3.8 meters difference between the transformations. I used the same EPSG codes.
For Proj 6.3:

```
echo 35.53 38.75 | cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:23036
```

Result: 719891.09   4292257.07
For PyQgis 3.10:

```
x, y = 35.53, 38.75
src = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
dest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(23036)
tform = QgsCoordinateTransform(src, dest, QgsProject.instance())
point = tform.transform(QgsPointXY(x, y))
print ("coordinates: ", point)
```

Result: coordinates:  <QgsPointXY: POINT(719887.53 4292255.79)>

I think Proj command line result is more accurate. Is there a way to fix it for QGIS?

Comment: Is there a relevant datum transformation set up in your QGIS project?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can get the same result except building QGIS with the "right" proj library

You are using Proj 6.3 on the command line whereas I think your QGIS is using Proj version 4 or 5. You can see the version going to menu "Help" -> "About" and you should see the following (in my case build against proj4 version 493 humanly named 4.9.3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Proj version of QGIS is 6.3.1. I shared the details in [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38190)